# Node JS Scoping

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

There's something wrong with my scoping that I'm not quite understanding here.  I have the following sample code:

```
/**
 * Created by David on 10/9/2016.
 */
var public = {};

//REQUIRES
var fs = require('fs');
var rl = require('readline');

//========================================
var configFile = './config';
public.configFile = configFile;

//========================================
public.readSettingsFile = function(conFile){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        try {
            console.log("Importing Settings");
            //read configuration file line by line
            var lineStream = rl.createInterface({
                input: fs.createReadStream(conFile === undefined ? configFile : conFile)
            });
            lineStream.on('line', function (line) {
                if(!line.startsWith('#')){
                    var splitLine = line.split('=');
                    switch(splitLine[0]){
                        case 'version':
                            public.version = splitLine[1];
                        break;
                        case 'basePath':
                            public.basePath = splitLine[1];
                        break;
                    }

                }
                resolve(public);
            });

        }catch(err){
            reject(err);
        }
    });
}

//========================================

module.exports = public;
```

I would expect, with the promises that on the .then, p should return, after a successful readSettingsFile, that public.version should now be included, but it's returning the following:

```
{ configFile: './config', readSettingsFile: [Function] }
```

The console.log in the switch statement is correctly returning:

```
0.1
```

Comment: You have not even invoked the `public.readSettingsFile` function. When you will - you will find out that your readline code is asynchronous.

Comment: A lot of what you are doing isn't clear and complete. Where do you actually call the readSettingsFile for example? Your promise also doesn't return a result on success.

Comment: Sorry, edited to try to give it more sense

Comment: @zerkms, i'm wondering with the way i have the promise set up, is it still acting async, so it's returning a valid promise despite not having finished reading?

Comment: `new Promise(function(resolve,reject){ reject(err); });` is just `Promise.reject(err)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue isn't with "scoping", but you don't understand how to use promises. I highly recommend both the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [David Walsh's blog post](https://davidwalsh.name/promises). I also recommend you start small and write some simple promises before trying something more complicated.

Now I'll answer your specific question. The reason you're not seeing what you want to see is that all your linestream business is asynchronous. You return the promise at the end of your function before you get to your switch statement. Basically, think of a promise as a whole function. But rather than returning a value, you're returning the promise of a value or an error. If you're throwing a promise in the middle of a function, your function is trying to do too many things and you need to separate your code out more.

This should be closer to what you want. This isn't perfect code, and it may not suit your needs, but hopefully it gets you on the right track. Good luck.

```
public.readSettingsFile = function(conFile){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var lineStream = rl.createInterface({
            input: fs.createReadStream(conFile === undefined ? configFile : conFile)
        });
        lineStream.on('line', function (line) {
            if(!line.startsWith('#')){
                var splitLine = line.split('=');
                // You don't need a switch statement for only one case
                if (splitLine[0] === 'version') {
                        public.version = splitLine[1];
                        console.log(public.version);
                        // You actually have to resolve something
                        resolve(public);
                } else {
                // There's a problem, reject it.
                reject("Some error message");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code I had was actually mostly correct, but as Paul mentioned in his answer, the resolve was in the wrong location.  the lineStream.on was running async and the resolve was located outside of it finishing, so it would run the 'resolve' path without having actually correctly finished.